# Check if network drive is mounted in a timely manner

Tags: 20.04, fstab, cifs, ls

I have a network drive mounted through cifs with the following configuracion in fstab:

```
/ip/drive /local_path cifs username=username,password=password,acl,rw 0 0
```

I need to know as soon as possible if the network drive is offline / not accessible.

Currently, i have a separate service running ls command periodically on the mounted path and checking if command gives a network error, but the moment the drive comes offline, ls command takes about 3 minutes to fail.

I could  run the command with a timeout (timeout 10 ls /local_path) but is there a better way to know if the drive is down without waiting for ls command to fail?

Comment: You could reduce the 3 minutes with the addition of the `x-systemd.device-timeout=10s` option in your fstab after the `rw`. Choose some value for the time out which is suitable. You could also script just checking for the existence of a file, rather than a full `ls`. A few lines of bash could just `test /localpath/lost+found` for example, to see if it's there quickly.

Comment: doing it using inotify / udev  would be quicker (ie. real time). But i do agree with popey: checking for the existance of 1 file or a directory should be enough. The mount command itself can tell you if something is mounted too. also possible:put it into  a systemd unit and then you can have it remount on failure.

Comment: I wonder if the `mountpoint` command would be useful here?

Comment: @popey Funly enough, I tried to check for the existence of a specific file before trying the ls command. Ubuntu tels me the file exists even when the network drive is down. I will be trying the x-systemd.device-timeout next.